# How do I migrate a photo library on macOS?

Tags: mac, photos

I'm manually migrating from a Macbook Pro to a new MBp. I would now like to store my photo library on an external disk, while continuing to let the default `Photos` app manage the photo library.

Simply copying the (large) `Photos Library.photoslibrary` folder using `Finder` is not enough. The meta data (favorites, people) are intact, but a subset of the pictures produces the message

[image]

which likely means that there is a hardlink to the actual photo on the old MBp.

How do I migrate a photo library on macOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like some photos are not in the Library itself, but referenced.

Try setting up a smart album on your old Mac - [Photo] [is] [Referenced] which will show up all photos outside the library.
After that, use File menu > Consolidate… which will pull them all into the main library.

Now you can copy the library structure to the new Mac.

[image]

Comment: Perfect: that's what I was missing. I'm still confused though. Some "missing/referenced photos" appear in low resolution when I double-click on them, as expected. But some photos appear (or seem to appear) in full resolution and yet `Photos` continues the missing-file report: "original photo is either offline or cannot be found." Does `Photos` have—as with iTunes/Music—a "reveal photo in Finder" feature anywhere so that I can get to the bottom of this?

Comment: As only the original photo is referenced, everything else must already be in the container, so only when you need to see the full image does it throw the error. There seems to be no 'reveal' at all. They do really like keeping the Photos structure deep & mysterious. It's far more complex than Music/iTunes & frankly I've never fully worked it out.